# Simulation on VHDL failing

Tags: vivado

I am newbie at Vivado and I'm trying to write a testbench to make a simulation. I'm trying to do the testbench for this component.

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity branchcontrol is
    Port ( PL : in STD_LOGIC;
           BC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           PC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           AD : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           Flags : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           PCLoad : out STD_LOGIC;
           PCValue : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end branchcontrol;

architecture Behavioral of branchcontrol is

signal Z,N,P,C,V: std_logic;

begin

Z <= Flags(3);        -- zero flag
N <= Flags(2);        -- negative flag
P <= not N and not Z; -- positive flag
C <= FLags(1);        -- carry flag
V <= Flags(0);        -- overflow flag


PCLoad <= PL and not(BC(3)) and ((not (BC(2)) and not (BC(1))) or ((not Z and BC(0)) and (BC(1) xnor N)) or (not BC(2) and(BC(0) xor Z)));

PCValue<=PC+AD;

end Behavioral;
```

And my testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity testBranchControl is
end testBranchControl;

architecture Behavioral of testBranchControl is

component branchcontrol
    Port ( 
           PL : in STD_LOGIC;
           BC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           PC : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           AD : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           Flags : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           PCLoad : out STD_LOGIC;
           PCValue : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0)
           );
end component;


signal PL, PCLoad: std_logic:='0'; 
signal BC, Flags: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000"; 
signal PC, AD, PCValue: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=(31 downto 0 => '0'); 

begin

    test_unit: branchcontrol port map(
         PL => PL, BC => BC, PC => PC, AD => AD,
         Flags => Flags, PCLoad => PCLoad,
         PC => PCValue); 

         process begin
            wait for 30 ns; 
            PL <= '0'; BC<="0000"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000101"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0000"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000101"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0010"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"00001100"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0010"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000101"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0011"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"00000101"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0011"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000001"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0100"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00001001"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0100"; Flags<="0100"; AD<=x"00001001"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0100"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"00001001"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0100"; Flags<="1100"; AD<=x"00001001"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0101"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000110"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0101"; Flags<="0100"; AD<=x"00001110"; 
            wait for 30 ns;    
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0101"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"00001110"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0101"; Flags<="1100"; AD<=x"00000000"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0110"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"00000000"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0110"; Flags<="0100"; AD<=x"00000000"; 
            wait for 30 ns;     
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0110"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"0000F0F0"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0110"; Flags<="1100"; AD<=x"0000F0F0"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0111"; Flags<="0000"; AD<=x"0000F0F0"; 
            wait for 30 ns;      
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0111"; Flags<="0100"; AD<=x"0000F0F0"; 
            wait for 30 ns;
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0111"; Flags<="1000"; AD<=x"0000AB00"; 
            wait for 30 ns;              
            PC<=PCValue; PL <= '1'; BC<="0111"; Flags<="1100"; AD<=x"0000AB00"; 
            wait for 30 ns;                                                     
            wait;
         end process;


end Behavioral;
```

The Vivado simply says that compile step failed with error(s) and that there was a error detected while running simulation. I'm also using the 2016.3 version of Vivado if that helps. I'm really stuck in this and I can't see mi mistake.

Can someone please help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: In the testbench you assign PC to PC and PCValue in the branchcontrol instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    test_unit: branchcontrol port map(
     PL => PL, BC => BC, PC => PC, AD => AD,
     Flags => Flags, PCLoad => PCLoad,
     PC => PCValue);
```

should be

```
    test_unit: branchcontrol port map(
     PL => PL, BC => BC, PC => PC, AD => AD,
     Flags => Flags, PCLoad => PCLoad,
     PCValue => PCValue);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast reply! You are right, I didn't see that. However the simulation still fails and the program doesn't say anything new... Is there anything more that is not right?

Comment: If you remove the unisim package (or add the library) from your testbench it should work